# Is Brownout Reset Circuit a standard or optional safety feature in an MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, reset, brownout

I've been using STM32 MCU's without paying attention to the BOR circuit:

[image]

Some datasheets indicate that the device has a built-in BOR circuit but some doesn't include such an information.

Is it always a MUST to have a BOR circuit? Is it a standard feature nowadays which might be covered by some other feature (such as Power On Reset) or is it an optional safety measure where we must implement by an external circuit if datasheet doesn't explicitly state the BOR circuit existence?

Comment: Note that the mere presence of a so-called BOR peripheral on an MCU chip does not guarantee that it will be, or even **can be** set up to reliably provide that function with a given configuration. For example, the tolerance limits of the BOR may make it impossible to guarantee that the processor will operate properly.

Comment: Could you explain the case a little more detailed?

Comment: For example, BOR operates at typical 4.0V with a range of 3.7 to 4.35. The MCU requires 4.0 to 5.5 V to be guaranteed to operate properly. So there is a 300mV range from 3.7 to 4.0V where behavior is undefined- it might spin motors, run heaters out of control, or trash non-volatile memory locations, for example. So you have to use an external BOR circuit if it is necessary  in the first place. That's a real example. They're also often poorly designed and draw a lot of current (significant in low power applications).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no governing body that decides what is "standard" in a microcontroller. You must always check the datasheet.

Comment: So a BOR circuit is always named as "BOR circuit" and it's functionality can not be merged with some other feature? In another words, there is some governing body that decides the name of the feature which is exactly "Brownout Reset"?

Comment: No.  There is at most defacto semi-standardization.  Not thinking of a great example at the moment, but different manufacturers can call similar capabilities by different names.

Comment: @ceremcem No, I didn't say it was always called BOR or that it can not be merged. The functionality you seek could be called by different names, have somewhat different characteristics, and could be integrated into other functional modules. You must read the datasheet.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson This means that we should go to "Reset Circuit" section of the MCU datasheet and expect to see a declaration of a circuit that "keeps the MCU under reset during power up until the supply voltage gets higher than the threshold level".

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific requirement for brown-out detect. However, typical product testing will involve testing low-line conditions and power-on / power-off cycling. Thus, a good design will include a circuit that guarantees correct startup and shut down.

For example, PC power supplies as part of the ATX spec include a "POWER GOOD" signal, that informs the rest of the system that the line voltage is adequate and the power outputs have reached their nominal values. This, in turn, controls CPU reset and other sequencing. More here: http://powersupply33.com/power-good-function-of-pc-power-supply.html

tl; dr version: no legal requirement, but it's good practice and is industry standard.